# React calling a function inside the render method leads to endless call stack

Tags: function, reactjs, call, render, callstack

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ajax from '../confing/ajax'
import $ from 'jquery'

class Categories extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isActive: '',
            categories: ''
        };
        this.switchLinkToActive = this.switchLinkToActive.bind(this);
    }

    switchLinkToActive(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let temp = [];
        console.log(event.target.id);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.isActive.length; i++) {
            if (i === parseInt(event.target.id)) {
                temp[i] = true;
            } else {
                temp[i] = false;
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            isActive: temp
        })

    }

    func() {
        let categories = [];
        ajax.request.get('categories').then((resp) => {
            let isActive = new Array(resp.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                isActive[i] = false;
            }
            this.setState({
                isActive: isActive
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                let element = resp[i];
                categories.push(<a key={element.id} href=""
                                   className={this.state.isActive[i] === true ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"}
                                   id={i} onClick={this.switchLinkToActive}>{element.name}</a>);

            }
            this.setState({
                categories: categories
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
       this.func();
        return (
            <div className="list-group col-3">
                {/*{this.state.categories}*/}
                <a key={2} href=""
                   className={this.state.isActive[2] === true ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"}
                   id={2} onClick={this.switchLinkToActive}>Custom lemenet</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Categories;
```

in this example i am calling `func()` inside of the `render()` method and it leads to something similar to stackoverflow, it just doesn't stop calling it. Anyway to fix that? I didn't really find any solutions to that. If i lets say just do a for loop inside of the render it works as intended it's called only once, so why is the function called endless amount of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your `ajax` calls usually in `componentDidMount`. It would look something like below

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.func();
}
```

In your `ajax` calls, once you get your response, set it to state. So your `func` would look something like below

```
func() {
    let categories = [];
    ajax.request.get('categories').then((resp) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
            resp[i].isActive = false;
        }
        this.setState({
            data : resp,
        });
    });
}
```

Your `render` would use the data in state and render the required DOM structure appropriately.

```
render() {

    return (
        <div className="list-group col-3">

            {
             (this.state.data || []).map((element, idx) => 
              categories.push(<a key={element.id} href=""
                               className={element.isActive ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"}
                               id={idx} onClick={this.switchLinkToActive}>{element.name}</a>);

             })
           }

            <a key={2} href=""
               className={this.state.isActive[2] === true ? "list-group-item list-group-item-action active" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action"}
               id={2} onClick={this.switchLinkToActive}>Custom lemenet</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever `setstate` inside render, instead do it in one of the [life cycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), in your case because you are doing an ajax request you should do that in `componentDidMount` [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: ok so i do in componentdidMout, then how do i send it to the render method

Comment: store it in `this.state`

Comment: you don't need to send the control to render method. Render method is called automatically as soon as state changes